# How to update perception_pcl?

Tags: ros, stacks, perception-pcl, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have ROS Electric binary install on Ubuntu 11.04. Today I need in last version of PCL 1.3 ( http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable/ - this one).
How should I update current stack?

I need some clarification. I have Makefile and CMakeLists.txt in /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl. They contains only some includes. Next, I go to ./pcl directory. There is Makefile, that contains next:

```
TARBALL = build/pcl-1.1.2.tar.gz
TARBALL_URL = https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/pcl/pcl-1.1.\
2.tar.gz
SOURCE_DIR = build/pcl
UNPACK_CMD = tar xzf
include $(shell rospack find mk)/download_unpack_build.mk

#SVN_DIR = build/pcl_trunk                                                      
## Developers, please use this URL:                                             
#SVN_URL = http://svn.pointclouds.org/pcl/trunk/                                
##SVN_PATCH =                                                                   
#SVN_REVISION=-r3434                                                            
#include $(shell rospack find mk)/svn_checkout.mk
```

So, when I uncomment SVN-related lines, comment tarball lines and try sudo make, I receive next:

Makefile:14: /svn_checkout.mk: No such file or directory make: *** No rule to make target/svn_checkout.mk'. Stop.` (that's obvious, there is no such file). Where I'm wrong?

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12214/how-to-update-perception_pcl?/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you need the latest trunk or the latest stable release? The perception_pcl_unstable is on the latest stable release. If you want latest trunk version, you comment the revision line in the makefile and you change the paths in your manifest to pcl-1.4 (which is the current state of trunk)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2011-12-06**:
I need in trunk version. In question I add my next problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-25**:
The issue with not finding the /svn_checkout.mk sounds like you don't have the mk package in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH which is in the ros stack.